# Getting two Scopes of same controller in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I just started to work with Angular, it's pretty nice to work with it, I just facing an issue of controllers's scope.

I have two files

1- header.html

2-dashboard.html

I included `header.html` in `dashboard.html`

I am performing two tasks with these files.
I have to use `ng-click="viewAll()"` which comes under `CategoryCtlr` controller in `header.html`, and after performing event I have to show the result in `dashboard.html`'s element which is here

```
<div class="row articleAll"></div>
```

if I am using this element in `header.html` it's working fine but, not in `dashboard.html`

I inject `ng-controller="CategoryCtlr"` in both files.

Can anybody help me to handle this task,

It will be grateful for me.

*Thank You*

Comment: Use ng-controller only once(in dashboard.html) and include the header.html inside it. No need to have an ng-controller in header.html. It would be helpful if you post your code.

Comment: Controller are not shared. If you using `CategoryCtlr` at multiple places, a new controller will be created evertime. Show some code. You have to look at scope inheritance and share services to share data.

Comment: Are these different templates residing in the same HTML document? or are they two different HTML documents?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create two controllers one is for header.html and another is for dashboard.html.
Lets say A_Cntrl is for dashboard and B_Cntrl is for header.html

```
Now as you are injecting header.html inside dashboard.html, A_Cntrl will be the parent controller for B_Cntrl

Use $emit() and $on concept of event notification from child to parent.

Now in viewAll() method,to notify the parent's controller, you put the following code:
$scope.$emit("Notify_To_Parent", $scope.flag(lets assume, change it as per your need);

In the parent controller, put the following code:
$scope.$on("Notify_To_Parent", function(event, state){
    // state is the value which is coming from child's controller
});
```

Try this, it will help you.